# Visual Studio 2012 Generator Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm looking for a way to make a project build and run as part of the build process in a solution.

Here's what I need:

1. First it compiles the "Generator Project", and in case of errors, it stops compiling.
2. Then it runs the "Generator Project", which creates some .cs files in other projects.
3. Then it compiles the rest of the projects.

I can see two ways of solving this.

- Create and manually run the "Generator Project" when changes are made.
- Construct a custom MSBuild script to do what I need.

While those two solutions work, I was hoping it might be possible to do it some easier/simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs to me that you might solve your problem by using [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) in the *generator project (**`GP`**)*, then include the target `.cs` files generated by the templates [as links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) into the *other projects (**`OTP`**)*, and finally add a reference to the `GP` on each of the `OTP` so that the custom build order gets honored. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I'll accept this. It wasn't the solution for me, as it requires a paid version of Visual Studio, but it's still the perfect solution for other in a similar situation.

Comment: @william-mindworx-mariager: OK, thanks for your comment and also for accepting the answer. It's kind of sad, though, that it is not good for you. That's about the only way I can think of to achieve your goal in a somewhat simpler way. I guess you'll have to stick to one of the options provided by yourself; I suggest going for the second one: a custom MSBuild task.

Comment: Yeah, the reason it's no good is because it's for an open source project, and I'm trying to make sure the tool-chain stays free as well. I did go with the first option actually, as I realized I wouldn't need to generate the files very often. The second options is the best choice for a free solution I think.